# Is reshape() same as contiguous().view()?

Tags: pytorch, reshape, tensor, torch

In PyTorch, for a tensor `x` is `x.reshape(shape)` always equivalent to `x.contiguous().view(shape)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There are some circumstances where `.reshape(shape)` can create a view, but `.contiguous().view(shape)` will create a copy.

Here is an example:

```
x = torch.zeros(8, 10)
y = x[:, ::2]
z0 = y.reshape(40)               # Makes a new view
z1 = y.contiguous().view(40)     # Makes a copy
```

We can confirm that `z0` is a new view of `x`, but `z1` is a copy:

```
> x.data_ptr() == z0.data_ptr()
True
> x.data_ptr() == z1.data_ptr()
False
```

Comment: Thanks. So is `.reshape(shape)` always preferable to `.contiguous().view(shape)`?

Comment: Unless you want to explicitly create a new copy, otherwise yes it is usually preferable.